# What does the "|" mean in the signature of MonadReader?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

When I'm reading "All About Monads", I bumped into the class type definitions like this:

```
class Monad m => MonadReader r (m :: * -> *) | m -> r where
  ...

class Monad m => MonadState s (m :: * -> *) | m -> s where      
  ...
```

I'm completely baffled by the vertical bar notation! Is that an "OR", is that a constraint? And what about `m->s`, what's that supposed to mean?

I know what is a type class, I know what are type constructors and type variables, and I also get what are Kinds about, I just cannot make any sense out of this!

Futhermore, when I resort to ghci, after typing `:k MonadState` `:k MonadReader` they both give me `* -> (* -> *) -> GHC.Prim.Constraint` back, that's just so weird!

Could somebody please shed some light on this?

Comment: I think it marks a functional dependency: [URL] (https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies)

Comment: In addition to `FunctionalDependencies`, this question asks about `KindSignatures` and `ConstraintKinds`. It thus cannot be an exact duplicate of any question from 2010, when these extensions did not exist.

Comment: @Michael The OP should learn to ask one question per question. In this case if you want to reopen the question it would be a good idea to remove all mentions of functional dependencies and instead ask about the constraints etc. Also: even then this has already been asked so this is probably just a case of changing duplicate target...